# Best way to receive all data over TCP socket

Tags: c#

I am sending base64 encoded XML from a web app to a listening Windows service but if i send a large amount of data (like 1500 characters or more) it seems like `stream.DataAvailable` will return false too early and the XML will be incomplete.

Is there a better way to wait for all of the data before continuing/exiting the while loop?

```
public static void loop(object obj)
    {
        TcpListener listener = (TcpListener) obj;

        // Enter the listening loop. 
        while (true)
        {
            // Set the event to nonsignaled state.
            tcpClientConnected.Reset();

            // Perform a blocking call to accept requests.
            listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(new AsyncCallback(DoAcceptTcpClientCallback), listener);

            // Wait until a connection is made and processed before  
            // continuing.
            tcpClientConnected.WaitOne();
        }
    }

    public static void DoAcceptTcpClientCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        // Get the listener that handles the client request.
        TcpListener listener = (TcpListener)ar.AsyncState;

        TcpClient client = listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(ar);

        // Signal the calling thread to continue.
        tcpClientConnected.Set();

        try {
            // Get a stream object for reading and writing
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
            stream.ReadTimeout = 30 * 1000;
            client.Client.ReceiveTimeout = 40;

            if (stream.CanRead)
            {
                // Buffer for reading data
                Byte[] bytes = new Byte[2048];

                // Translate data bytes to an ASCII string.
                string requestBody = "";

                int numberOfBytesRead = 0;
                // Incoming message may be larger than the buffer size. 
                do
                {
                    Array.Clear(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                    numberOfBytesRead = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                    requestBody = string.Concat(requestBody, Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, numberOfBytesRead));
                }
                while (stream.DataAvailable);

                try
                {
                    Control controller = new Control(requestBody);
                    controller.dispatch(stream);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    string error_msg = "Controller exception: " + e.Message;
                    error_msg += "\n" + e.StackTrace;
                    error_msg += "\n" + requestBody;
                    log(error_msg);
                }
            }

            stream.Close();
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            string error_msg = "Socket exception: " + e.Message;
            log(error_msg);
        } finally
        {
            client.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Send a length header before the actual data and then read until the number of bytes read matches the length.

Comment: You need to formulate a protocol that either prefixes a length token or uses an end-of-data sequence, and wait until that condition is met.  Is there a reason for base64 encoding XML? A receiving socket can consume whatever you tell it to without the need for additional encoding.

Comment: My bad, it's not base64 encoded. i was thinking of something else. I have base64 encoded content in the xml that contains escape sequences/unicode characters

Comment: aside comment: use socket.Poll() and socket.Receive(), using streams adds an extra layer of buffering that can cause issues/lag/extra fragmentation (admittedly that's mostly with discrete hardware, but better to use the more reliable methods everywhere in case your 'other end' changes.)

Comment: As you've discovered, `stream.DataAvailable` means "right now".

Comment: I've changed it to `while (!requestBody.TrimEnd().EndsWith("</transaction>"));` and it seems to be working better so far. Thanks!

Comment: @MarshallHouse that is not going to work either because the end of one "message" can be combined with the next so you could get `...</transaction><transa` if it decided to include the next messages `<transa` as part of the packet. You need a protocol to do some kind of [message framing](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html) and read till you get the entire message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rule of thumb: never-ever place raw data on socket. You have to wrap it into a protocol that can help both parties to understand: is there any data to read, is there all data sent, etc.

As noted in comments, simplest way is to prepend your data with a fixed-length integer value that indicates a length of further data to follow. In more sophisticated cases you could reuse things like [ProtocolBuffers](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_Buffers) or [Apache Thrift](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Thrift).

Next station here could be your HTTP server or something like that (as HTTP can be customized with such things as new header fields, encryption, caching etc. etc. etc...)